# Getting internal server error when posting to my website, but not when deleting posts

Tags: reactjs, firebase, express, axios

I can't seem to figure out how my server is having trouble fulfilling a post request. It works perfectly fine in postman when I provide this JSON below

`{
  "name": "post11111111111",
  "images": "image/path",
  "link": "https://etsy.com",
  "info": "this is a painting",
  "price": "75",
  "itemCategory": "painting",
  "available": "true",
  "highEnd": "false"
}`

But when making the post request with axios inside my client program, it returns a 500 err. What's strange is that delete (and getAll) work just fine. It's a react app using a node/express/firebase server. I'll attach everything on the front end such as my actions and components that I think is relevant (I'm using react and redux for practice).

dataActions.js

```
import { SET_POSTS, LOADING_DATA, DELETE_POST, POST_PRODUCT, SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI } from "../types";
import axios from 'axios';
//GET ALL PRODUCTS
export const getPosts = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_DATA });
    axios.get('/posts')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_POSTS,
                payload: []
            })
        })
}
//POST PRODUCT
export const postProduct = (newPost) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
    axios.post('/post', newPost)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: POST_PRODUCT,
                payload: res.data
            })
            console.log("success");
            dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_ERRORS,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        })
}
//DELETE PRODUCT
export const deletePost = (postId) => (dispatch) => {
    axios.delete(`/post/${postId}`)
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: DELETE_POST, payload: postId })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

dataReducer.js

```
import { SET_POSTS } from '../types';
import { LOADING_DATA, DELETE_POST, POST_PRODUCT/*, SET_POST*/ } from '../types';

const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    post: {},
    loading: false
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case LOADING_DATA:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case SET_POSTS:
            return{
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload,
                loading: false
            }
        case DELETE_POST:
            let index = state.posts.findIndex(post => post.postId === action.payload);
            state.posts.splice(index, 1);
            return {
                ...state
            }
        case POST_PRODUCT:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts]
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

PostProduct.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import MyButton from "../util/MyButton";

//MUI Stuff
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DeleteOutline from "@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline";
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
//REDUX
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { postProduct } from "../redux/actions/dataActions";

const styles = {
  form: {
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  image: {
    margin: "20px auto 20px auto",
    width: "50px"
  },
  pageTitle: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  textField: {
    margin: "10px auto 10px auto"
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: 20,
    postition: "relative"
  },
  customError: {
    color: "red",
    fontSixe: "0.8rem",
    marginTop: 10
  },
  progress: {
    position: "absolute"
  },
  submitButton: {
      position: "relative"
  },
  progressSpinner: {
      position: 'absolute'
  },
  closeButton: {
      position: 'absolute',
      left: '90%',
      top: '10%'
  }
};

class PostProduct extends Component {
    state = {
        open: false,
        name: '',
        errors: {}
    };
    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
            this.setState({
                errors: nextProps.UI.errors
            })
        }
    }
    handleOpen = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true })
    }
    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false })
    }
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    }
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postProduct({ body: this.state.body })
    }
    render(){
        const { errors } = this.state;
        const { classes, UI: {loading }} = this.props;
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <MyButton onClick={this.handleOpen} tip="Post a Product">
              <AddIcon />
            </MyButton>
            <Dialog
              open={this.state.open}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
              fullWidth
              maxWidth="sm"
            >
              <MyButton
                tip="close"
                onClick={this.handleClose}
                tipClassName={classes.closeButton}
              >
                <CloseIcon />
              </MyButton>
              <DialogTitle>Post the new Product</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                  <TextField
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    lable="Post Product"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="name"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="images"
                    type="text"
                    lable="image"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="image"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="itemCategory"
                    type="text"
                    lable="Painting"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="Painting"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="link"
                    type="text"
                    lable="link"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="https://etsy.com"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="info"
                    type="text"
                    lable="blah blah blah"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="info"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="price"
                    type="text"
                    lable="Price"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="75.99"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="available"
                    type="text"
                    lable="available?"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="true"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="highEnd"
                    type="text"
                    lable="High-end or not?"
                    multiline
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="false"
                    error={errors.body ? true : false}
                    helperText={errors.body}
                    className={classes.textFields}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    fullWidth
                  />
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submitButton}
                    disabled={loading}
                  >
                    Submit
                    {loading && (
                      <CircularProgress
                        size={30}
                        className={classes.progressSpinner}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Button>
                </form>
              </DialogContent>
            </Dialog>
          </Fragment>
        );
    }


} // END CLASS

PostProduct.propTypes = {
    postProduct: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    UI: state.UI
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { postProduct })(withStyles(styles)(PostProduct))
```

The front end code is in this repository here: https://github.com/jIrwinCline/planum-front
and the backend here: https://github.com/jIrwinCline/planum-magic

Thanks for any help. I know this is a big question...

---

THANKS jfriend00!!!

---

Thank you, I got past that error. I was not laying out the object properties that I wanted and instead just had 'body: this.state.body' in my request. where I actually needed the entire JSON content.

Now I'm running into the issue that I'm actually not getting any of the submitted information into the card that is being created. Let me know if you see anything on that.

a few errors coming out are

```
index.js:1375 Material-UI: either `children`, `image` or `src` prop must be specified. 
    in CardMedia (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardMedia)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardMedia)) (at Post.js:55)
    in Post (created by WithStyles(Post))
    in WithStyles(Post) (created by Connect(WithStyles(Post)))
    in Connect(WithStyles(Post)) (at products.jsx:18)
    in products (created by Connect(products))
    in Connect(products) (created by Router.Consumer)
    in Router.Consumer (created by Route)
    in Route (at App.js:44)
    in App (at src/​index.js:6)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1375
r @ backend.js:6
CardMedia @ CardMedia.js:41
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16295
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:18145
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:20170
beginWork$$1 @ react-dom.development.js:25699
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:24646
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:24622
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:24211
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:12263
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:821
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12209
flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:12258
flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12246
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24332
notify @ Subscription.js:23
notifyNestedSubs @ Subscription.js:65
handleChangeWrapper @ Subscription.js:70
dispatch @ redux.js:221
e @ VM889:1
(anonymous) @ index.js:11
dispatch @ redux.js:638
(anonymous) @ dataActions.js:25
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ dataActions.js:23
(anonymous) @ index.js:8
(anonymous) @ redux.js:476
PostProduct.handleSubmit @ PostProduct.js:83
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:337
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:386
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:439
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:454
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:585
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:610
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:713
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:722
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:694
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:739
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:881
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:5834
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24342
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1417
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:5930
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6047
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5950
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:821
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12209
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24359
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1442
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5917
index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `postId` is marked as required in `DeletePost`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in DeletePost (created by WithStyles(DeletePost))
    in WithStyles(DeletePost) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Post.js:51)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(CardContent))
    in ForwardRef(CardContent) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardContent)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(CardContent)) (at Post.js:60)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(Card))
    in ForwardRef(Card) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Card)) (at Post.js:54)
    in Post (created by WithStyles(Post))
    in WithStyles(Post) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at products.jsx:18)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at products.jsx:22)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Grid))
    in ForwardRef(Grid) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Grid)) (at products.jsx:21)
    in products (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:44)
    in Switch (at App.js:42)
    in div (at App.js:41)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:39)
    in Provider (at App.js:38)
    in ThemeProvider (at App.js:37)
    in App (at src/index.js:6)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't really work well when you keep adding more questions onto your question.  I know that's not always how your problem works, but it should be question/answer.  New question/new answer.  Not question/answer/edit more question/more answer/edit more question/more answer.  So, perhaps you should gather up all the relevant info to your new problem and ask a new question.  You can then indicate to the community that this one is done by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that showed the `postProduct()` data format issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your axios code, you are calling `postProduct()` like this:

```
this.props.postProduct({ body: this.state.body })
```

You say that Postman works when you give it this:

```
{
  "name": "post11111111111",
  "images": "image/path",
  "link": "https://etsy.com",
  "info": "this is a painting",
  "price": "75",
  "itemCategory": "painting",
  "available": "true",
  "highEnd": "false"
}
```

There's no way those are the same structure.  There's no top level `body` property in the Postman request and all those other top level properties are not present in the Axios version.

---

It's probably worth just logging exactly what the incoming request is on your server for both requests and you should be able to immediately see what's different between the two requests.

Comment: Wow. OK. You're right. I added. ```handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postProduct({
          name: this.state.name,
          images: this.state.images,
          link: this.state.link,
          info: this.state.info,
          price: this.state.price,
          itemCategory: this.state.itemCategory,
          available: this.state.available,
          highEnd: this.state.highEnd
        });
    }```... I'm getting a new error now but this is an awesome start

Comment: @JakobinIrwin - If this solved your original problem, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here which can lead to additional privileges on the site.

Answer (score 0):

THANKS jfriend00!!!

Thank you, I got past that error. I was not laying out the object properties that I wanted and instead just had 'body: this.state.body' in my request. where I actually needed the entire JSON content.

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, it is custom to accept the answer that solved the problem for your (once the system allows that). If you want to comment on jfriend00's answer, do that with the comment function under that answer.